# How to emit messages between many nodes js servers

Tags: node.js, sockets, redis, socket.io

As I am newbie, need some help. I need to emit messages between many nodeJS  servers. I need the communication to be server to server, not server to browser(what are the most patterns I found).
For what I read, I may need redis. I have already installed it and it's ready to accept connections.
If I try this code from socket.io

```
var io = require('socket.io')(3000);
var redis = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));
io.emit('hi', 'all sockets');
```

... nothing happens. Any advises what is missing or other patterns I can implement? Thanks!

Comment: I think you can simply define a route in your app, like `app.post("/message", ... )` and then call it from another server with a regular HTTP call, using for instance `request.post( serverURL + "/message", {data})`. It would work both ways. That's what I would do, as a first approach.

Comment: Thanks, but I need communication between multiple nodes/servers. If something happens on server A, the rest connected servers (B, C, D, etc) should receive the data, send by A. That's why I think using redis will solve my case, but not sure how to implement the logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use RabbitMQ for messaging.

RabbitMQ is a very powerful concept when building applications that need to scale. It is a common pattern when building distributed systems to have a work queue that separates work producers from consumers (workers).

- Messages are sent by Producers
- Messages are delivered to Consumers
- Messages go through a Channel

[image]

There are many messaging patterns, which have been written about ad nauseum. Two noteworthy messaging patterns in the context of RabbitMQ are Competing Consumers and Remote Procedure Call.

**Using Rabbit MQ with a competing consumers messaging pattern**

To illustrate, consider a user who needs to import a large amount of data. Processing this data is a CPU-intensive task. A naive implementation could be:

- User uploads data (request)
- Server processes the data
- Respond to the user with a result (reply)

If you try to process this data directly using a Node.js process, you will be blocking event loop. Any requests that come in during data processing will have to wait, which is not good. The system is unresponsive.  A better approach would be:

- User uploads data (request)
- Server sends a message to a queue
- A response is sent to the user with a message that data has been received successfully and will be processed (reply).

The message that was sent to a queue contains all required information (user information, file location,etc.), and will be picked up and processed by an available consumer (worker). The user will be notified after the data has been processed. This approach (fire-and-forget) has several advantages:

- The server is able to handle other requests immediately
- Processing is delayed if there are no resources available at that moment
- Processing is retried if it fails the first time

In the above example we applied a competing consumer pattern. When there is a message in a queue, any of the consumers could potentially receive it. Simply speaking, consumers compete with each other to be the message receiver.
[image]